# Setting up PayPal Client-Side Single Payout in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The [Client-side REST integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) documentation describes creating an express checkout for one or more items.

Is there any way I can do a PayPal single Payout client-side? I'm building a React app and need to be able to PAY a USER a given amount of money with the press of a button. I don't need a normal checkout button, I need to transfer money from my PayPal account to a user's.

I've looked into the PayPal REST SDK but want to handle it client-side if possible.

Comment: did you find a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to integrate Nodejs/express for a PayPal checkout button.

As you can see in the link you provided you have a section named: Integrate.

In this section you have [how-a-client-integration-works](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#how-a-client-integration-works).

I would recommend you to read all the documentation though, and follow instructions.

Comment: I'm not implementing a checkout button, I'm attempting to pay a user based on a balance that I'm storing in my database. This can be done via a feature called PayPal Payouts, but I'm trying to figure out if I can do it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

For your React app, you can also use the React component which is bundled in the PayPal Checkout javascript.

You can find instructions on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#reactjs-element).

Remember to pass every property to the component. In the example, there's no `env` property, so if you want to run tests against Sandbox double check you're passing it as a prop.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not trying to complete a checkout, I'm trying to pay the user money from my PayPal account. PayPal has what are called "Payouts" for this purpose, but I'm not sure how to do it client-side or if it's even possible.